# BuildFire: Tracking Commerce and Conversion Analytics

Tags: firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics, buildfire

I am attempting to track certain events in Buildfire's platform and have a few questions. I've integrated Firebase into a plugin not using the Buildfire API but by following Firebase's steps to integrating with a web app.

I'd like to be able to register the following events but don't see them mentioned in the Buildfire Wiki:

1. When a user signs up (creates an account) on an app - I believe Firebase registers users anonymously the first time they use an app since Firebase has been integrated but was wondering if there was a signup event when a user actually creates an account to distinguish between people who view the app and those who create an account
2. Paywall view (when a user tries to see premium content and is directed to the paywall).
3. When a user subscribes to a paid plan - additionally, I'd like to access the subscription information such as the price of the subscription.

These events would help drive funnels and deliver better conversion rate statistics. I've looked but just haven't found the documentation related to tracking these events within Buildfire. I've looked at the getUser methods under [Authentication](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Auth) in Buildfire's API but don't see any user information returned regarding subscriptions.

Any information would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish what you are looking for. I'll try to describe several so you can pick the method that best suits you.

1. Use the BuildFire integration with Firebase. This doesn't really change much on your implementation. However, you now will have the BuildFire Auth Servers sending your Firebase server, secure user information along with User Tags. If you have the user tagged when they view premium content, then you can run queries on this directly in firebase.
   https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Buildfire-Firebase-Integration
2. Send your Analytics to BuildFire. This way you have one spot to view the users' journey
   https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-capture-Analytics-for-your-plugin
3. For more advanced analytics and funnel creation you can send your analytics to BuildFire and use BuildFire's integration with Segment.io which will allow you to pipe the data into your database, google analytics, mixpanel, or anyone of the hundreds of integrations they have.
   https://learn.buildfire.com/en/articles/3225298-how-to-integrate-segment-with-your-app-for-additional-analytics